# Use multiple graphical windows in OCaml

Tags: graphics, ocaml

OCaml comes with the [`Graphics`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Graphics.html) module which allows the use of a graphical window.

**Is it possible to open two graphical window, and switch between them ?**

The `Graphics` module provides machine-independent tools but in case of a negative answer, perhaps it would also be interesting to have solutions for different window system, such as X11.

Comment: No, the display is a global variable: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/28c337fecbebfc064c06ae0ba35a1107b0b58493/otherlibs/graph/open.c#L31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the Graphics module API and I don't see support for multiple windows. I would assume Graphics was intended as something useful but simple enough to be part of the base OCaml release.

For more complex graphics, it makes sense just to provide OCaml bindings to an existing library. If I go to opam.ocaml.org/packages and search for "graphics" I see a few possibilities.

I have done OpenGL coding in OCaml but in fact I had to build some wrappers for OS-native GUI functionality to create the windows. This was many years ago, however.

Answer (score 1):

The `Graphics` module is quite limited and is more intended as a simple basic library for teaching purposes. A possible replacement for `Graphics` might be the tsdl package which is a thin wrapper around the `SDL` C library which should work on most platforms.